# Reproducing Results / Random-Seed / Sensitivity Analysis

Tags: netlogo, random-seed

I'm building a cost effectiveness model (infectious disease related) in NetLogo consisting of an intervention and "status quo" cohort that should behave identically except for the influence of the intervention.  I can reproduce base case results (default parameter values) using the random-seed statement. However, when I change parameters influence intervention efficacy (e.g., compliance) it changes the random number generation process and then causes the outcomes in the status quo cohort to change.  How can I get around this? How do I isolate one cohort from changes taking place in another cohort with respect to the random number generation process? the with-local-randomness statement doesn't really help me ..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you face two serious problems: NetLogo really does not provide access to random number generators other than the global one, and much of the access to that PRNG is implicit.  So for example, whenever you use `ask`, you are implicitly drawing from the global PRNG.

You may be able to use `with-local-randomness`.  E.g., use it every time you `ask` turtles *outside* the status-quo cohort to do something.  Or, to use `with-local-randomness` for the special cohort, you could start the simulation by generating a seed sequence that you then consume as the simulation runs, resetting the random state each time you `ask` that cohort to do something (or generate random numbers, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Do the cohorts need to be run simultaneously (ie do they interact)? If not, could you simply run two completely separate experiments - one for the control and one for the intervention scenario.

Comment: Its a great suggestion. Two issues: first, I like showing the simultaneously because it facilities better effectiveness comparisons (otherwise will have to store the results of the status quo scenario and then compare them after the other runs - a bit cumbersome) and the users can see when the intervention becomes cost saving (the discounted cost plots cross).  The idea was to build something that practitioners could use.  My other concern is that it doesn't totally resolve the issue because the parameter changes to the intervention cohort influence the intervention outcomes in unintended ways

Comment: Makes sense. Conceptually I think your problem is that you really want to do analysis, and NetLogo generates data (through the simulations) but doesn't provide analysis across simulations. For that, you need to go to R or Excel. It doesn't help you now, but I am hoping to build an analysis tool early next year that will take the output from BehaviorSpace and allow various comparison charts to be automatically created for exploratory analysis.